# Create one doubly linked list to represent all the 52 cards in a deck

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to create a program that uses a doubly linked list to represent all the 52 cards in a deck. How do I do that?
I am supposed to create the classes and methods and can not use the existing java classes.

Here is my Doubly Linked List

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> rear;

    public DoublyLinkedList(){
        head = null;
        rear = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return head ==null;
    }

    public void insertFirst (T dd){
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(dd);
        if (isEmpty())
            rear = newNode;
        else
            head.setPrevious(newNode);

            newNode.setNext(head);
            head = newNode;
    }

    //0. Only can use this to insert AFTER first node
    public boolean insertAfter(int key, T dd){
        Node<T> current = head;
        //1. traverse and check if key exisst and reference it using a node
        while ((Integer) current.getData()!=key){
            current = current.getNext();
            if(current == null)
                return false; //cannot find it
        }

        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(dd); //make new link

        if (current == rear) //2. if key is the rear node,
        {
            newNode.setNext(null);
            rear = newNode;     //3. Set reat to point to the new node
        }
        else //4. if key is not the rear link,
        {
            //5. handle the 2 link changes that is right hand side of the new node
            newNode.setNext(current.getNext());
            current.getNext().setPrevious(newNode);
        }
        //6. handle the 2 link changes that is left hand sid of the node
        newNode.setPrevious(current);
        current.setNext(newNode);
        return true; //found it, insert
    }

    public Node deleteFirst(){
        Node<T> temp = head;
        if (head.getNext() == null)
            rear = null; //to indicate empty DLL
        else
            head.getNext().setPrevious(null);
        head = head.getNext();
        return temp;
    }

    public Node deleteLast(){
        Node<T> temp = rear;
        if (head.getNext() == null)
            head = null; //to indicate empty DLL
        else
            rear.getPrevious().setNext(null);
        rear = rear.getPrevious();
        return temp;
    }

    public Node deleteKey(int key){
        Node<T> current = head;
        while ((Integer) current.getData() != key){
            current = current.getNext();
            if (current == null)
                return null; //cannot find it
        }
        if (current == head) //found it; head item?
            head = current.getNext();
        else
            current.getPrevious().setNext(current.getNext());

        if (current == rear) //rear item?
            rear = current.getPrevious();
        else
            //not rear
            current.getNext().setPrevious(current.getPrevious());
        return current; //return value
    }

    public void displayForward (){
        System.out.print("List (head to rear): ");
        Node<T> current = head; //start at beginning
        while (current != null) //until end of list,
        {
            current.displayLink(); //display data
            current = current.getNext(); //move to next link
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void displayBackward(){
        System.out.print("List (Backwards) : ");
        Node<T> current = rear;
        while (current != null){
            current.displayLink();
            current = current.getPrevious();
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Here is my Node

```
public class Node <T> {
private T data;
    private Node next;
    private Node previous;              // previous link in list

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }    
    public void setPrevious(Node previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }
    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    } 
    public void displayLink(){ System.out.print(data + " " );}

}
```

Here is my main class

```
public class Question {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userChoice = 0;
        DoublyLinkedList dll = new DoublyLinkedList();
        String[] suits = {"C", "D", "H", "S"}; //arraylist? not supposed to use that...
        String[] cardValues = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};

        int cardsInDeck = 52;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter a number. \nIf you want to pick a card from "
                    + "FRONT, enter 1. \n"
                    + "If you want to pick a card from BACK, enter 2.\n"
                    + "If you want to SWAP 4 PAIRS OF RANDOM CARD, enter 3.\n"
                    + "If you want to SPLIT THE DECK, enter 4.\n"
                    + "Number: ");
            userChoice = sc.nextInt();

            if (userChoice == 1){

            }
        }

    }

}
```

How do I create the deck of cards making use of only doubly LinkedList and not arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the constructor of DoublyLinkedList to something like this:

```
/**
 * The class represents a full deck of cards. 
 * Each card is represented by a Node.
 * It is initialized so each Node (card), accept the first,
 * is linked to its previous card, and each node but last, 
 * is linked to its next card in the deck.
 */
public class DoublyLinkedList<T> {

    //13 cards per suit
    String[] cardValues = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
    //4 suits
    String[] suits = {"C", "D", "H", "S"};

    //an array to hold (references to) 4*13 Nodes. Each node represents a card
    private Node<T> nodes[] = new Node[cardValues.length * suits.length];

    public DoublyLinkedList(){

        int cardCounter = 0;

        //Iterate over all suits
        for( String suit : suits) {

            //Iterate over all cards
            for(String card : cardValues) {

                //create a Node representing a card 
                Node<T> node = new Node( suit+card ); // substitute suit+card for "real" data

                //define previous node to every node but first 
                if (cardCounter > 0) {
                    //link this node to previous one 
                    node.setPrevious(nodes[cardCounter-1]);

                    //link previous node to this one 
                    nodes[cardCounter-1].setNext(node);
                }
                //add node to array
                nodes[cardCounter] = node;

                cardCounter++;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return nodes.length ==0; //no mode in array 
    }

    //add more methods / functions as needed
}
```

If it is not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: why do you do this `private Node<T> nodes[] = new Node[cardValues.length * suits.length];`?

Comment: it creates an array to hold all nodes (all cards) . The size of the array is 52 - 4 suits * 13 cards.   (you can replace it with private Node<T> nodes[] = new Node[52];  )

Comment: I added comments to clarify, and a missing linkage to "next" node.

Answer (score 0):

Nice use of generics. Do yourself the favour of being consistent: never use just `Node`, always `Node<T>`.

You may want to declare a Card class holding the suit and value of a card. You may also just use strings for cards, like this:

```
for (String suit : suits) {
    for (String value : cardValues) {
        dll.insertFirst(value + " of " + suit);
    }
}
```

Let me know whether it helps.